# Detect if ScrollView is manually scrolled by user or is debouncing automatically?

Tags: animation, swiftui, scrollview

I am currently making an animation identical to the snap refreshing animation of the chat section. The refreshing only occurs after scrolling to specific extent and the user then unholds so the scrollview automatically bounces to its original place. if the user manually scrolls back to the original position, no refreshing occurs and thus the animation too doesn't occur.

So far, I have been able to get the scrolling offset using GeometryReader (where the scrollview is embedded inside) and a State variable to track the offset (so i can animate things as the scroll is occuring). But I have been unable to finalize the animation by knowing if the user decided to refresh by unholding and allowing automatic debounce or if the user manually returned the scrollview back to the original place.

```
struct HomeView: View {
@State private var scrollOffset: CGFloat = CGFloat.zero
// view model and others....

var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.vertical) {
        GeometryReader(content: { geometry in
            LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(vm.friends.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    let friend = vm.friends[index]
                    FriendCell(userData: friend) {
                        self.dragOffset = $0
                    } onChat: {
                        //
                    } onProfile: {
                        vm.friendProfileSelected = friend
                    } onCamera: {
                        //
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: geometry.frame(in: .global).origin.y) {
                self.scrollOffset = $1
            }
        })
        
    }
    .background(alignment: .top, content: SnapAnimation)
}

private func SnapAnimation() -> some View {
    LinearGradient(colors: [.gradientLight, .gradientDark], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
        .frame(height: scrollOffset)
        .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
            var state : Int {
                if scrollOffset < 100 {
                    return 0
                }
                else if self.scrollOffset < 260 {
                    return 1
                }
                else {
                    return 2
                }
            }
            var offset: CGFloat {
                if scrollOffset < 10 {
                    // hide
                    return 35
                }
                else if scrollOffset < 35 {
                    // increase
                    return (35 - scrollOffset) + 4.5
                    
                }
                else {
                    return 4.5
                }
            }
            
            Image("state \(state)")
                .offset(y: offset)
        }
    
    
    
}
}
```

this is the animation so far, but the detecting part i dont know how to do it.